# Datatables.net как при выгрузке в Excel данные из одной ячейки разнести по нескольким

Tags: excel, datatable, export

Есть таблица datatables.net в ячейку которой приходят данные. При выгрузке в excel нужно разнести эти данные в три разные клетки таблицы excel. Как это сделать? 
Вот код кнопки выгрузки:

```
                  buttons: [
                         {
                             extend: 'excelHtml5',
                             className: 'tableButtonExcel',
                             title: 'Table' + moment().format(TIME_STAMP_FORMAT),
                             text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>',
                             titleAttr: 'Download Excel',
                             header: false,
                           }
```

Вот как выглядит таблица при выгрузке сейчас:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как она должна выглядеть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пробовала добавить:

```
 exportOptions: {
                format: {
                       body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
                         var data1 = data.split(",");
                         return data1[0] + '</t>' + data1[1] + '</t>' + data1[2];
                        }
              }
```

все равно при выгрузке данные помещаются в одну ячейку.

Comment: у Вас данные видимо приходят не как массив, а как строка - поэтому data[0] + '</t>' ... не работает, попробуйте разбивать строку как то так: data.split(",")[0] + '</t>'

Comment: я просто сокращенно написала. Проблема в том, что потом это все так и вставляется в ячейку excel: "value1 + '</t>' + value2 + '</t>' + value3" - это я вижу в файле в одной ячейке после выгрузки

Comment: попробуйте добавить 3 функции (это конечно костыль), но как вариант